# How to override used decorator?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7, decorator, python-decorators

I'm used django with django-fsm, and I want to override/reuse transition decorator for field in Model. For example, its state field with inherited TransitionMixin class for my model:

a) base model in django

```
class BlogPage(TransitionMixin(myapp, mymodelname, state_obj, state), models.Model):
      page_id = IntegerField(...)
      state = StateObject(...) # its tuple with values similar on ('d', draft,)/etc.
```

b) mixin for class

```
from django_fsm import transition

class TransitionMixin(object):
    def __init__(self, appname, modelname, field, state_obj):
        self.appname = appname
        self.modelname = modelname
        self.State = state_obj
        self.state = field

    # how to define there dynamically decorator with users parameters?
    @transition(field=state, source=State.READY_FOR_REVIEW,
                target=State.PUBLISHED,
                permission='{0}.can_publish_{1}'.format(self.appname,
                                                        self.modelname))
    def publish(self):
        pass

    # some other methods for state field, with @transition decorator
    # ...
```

How I can do this? Maybe use metaclasses or perhaps exists more flexible solution?